# Rails, tips for solving this n+1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an employee view, where are listed all skills, which are written in the skills table on my db. For every employee, all skills are displayed, just as want it to.

Employees and skills are related to each other as has many :through association.

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :employeeskillsets, foreign_key: "employee_id"
  has_many :skills, through: :employeeskillsets
end

class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :employeeskillsets, foreign_key: "skill_id"
  has_many :employees, through: :employeeskillsets
end 

class Employeeskillset < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :employee, foreign_key: 'employee_id'
  belongs_to :skill, foreign_key: 'skill_id'
end
```

All those skills are displayed as buttons, which are toggles to enable/disable that particular skill on that employee (per click a direct insert/delete, no extra commit needed).

```
<%= link_to apply_skill_employee_path(employee: @employee, skill_id: skill.id), method: :put, remote: :true do %>
<%= skill.name %></div><% end %>
```

But now, I want to the buttons to be shown colored, when you load the page. If the skill is already enabled, the buttoncolor should be green, else grey. And here begins my problem:
My app checks each skill with one separate select statement. I use the following code for this:

```
<%= link_to apply_skill_employee_path(employee: @employee, skill_id: skill.id), method: :put, remote: :true do %>
  <% if @employee.skills.exists?(skill.id) %>
    <div class="button skill e-true"><%= skill.name %></div>
  <% else %>
    <div class="button skill"><%= skill.name %></div>
  <% end %>
```

I have already tried to use includes, but it seems, the exists? checks each skill independently.

Does anybody here have a suggestion, how I could solve this, by using one single select?

Thanks in advance, I hope I have mentioned everything, what is necessary.

Edit 1: I forgot to mention, that i render this through a partial (if that is important to know).
And here is the current used @employee var in the employees_controller.

```
@employee = Employee.find_by(id: params[:id])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`pluck`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)ing ids, and then check for [`include?`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/include%3F) as you don't need to fetch all attributes of `skills`

```
<% skills = @employee.skills.pluck(:id) %>
<%= link_to apply_skill_employee_path(employee: @employee, skill_id: skill.id), method: :put, remote: :true do %>
<% if skills.include?(skill.id) %>
  <div class="button skill e-true"><%= skill.name %></div>
<% else %>
  <div class="button skill"><%= skill.name %></div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `skill` is also an active record model, you can use `include?` on the employee's skills collection to check if the employee has a particular skill.

```
@employee.skills.include?(skill)
```

This way you are free to use `includes` clause to eagerly load employees' skills.

Answer (score 0):

This will not fire the additional query

```
<% if @employee.skill_ids.exists?(skill.id) %>
```

Also to avoid `n+1` in the following line

```
apply_skill_employee_path(employee: @employee, skill_id: skill.id)
```

Make sure you are including `skills`

```
@employee = Employee.includes(:skills).where(......)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Rails way is far simpler.

When you use the `has_many` macro in ActiveRecord it also creates a `_ids` method that can be used to add or remove relations with an array:

```
@employee.skills_ids = [1,2,3]
```

This also works with indirect assocations with the `:through` option.

You can use this together with the form collection helpers to create select or checkbox tags:

```
<%= form_for(@employee) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :skill_ids, 'Skills' %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:skills_ids, Skill.all, :id, :name) %>
<% end %>
```

To avoid an extra query you can do a left outer join in the controller:

```
def edit
  # left_outer_joins is new in Rails 5
  # see https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/24/support-for-left-outer-joins-in-rails-5.html
  @employee.left_outer_joins(:skills).find(params[:id])
end
```

You also don't need a silly extra method in your controller for something that should be handled as a normal update. KISS.

Comment: That would really tidy up my code, but I don't know, how I could use this within my categorization, which is structured like this: Topcategories:{Skills, Categories:{Skills, Subcategories:{Skills}}}

Comment: That seems like a not so optimal layout - you should only really need one category model and make it self joining to build heirarchy. But thats a completely different question.

Comment: I just created a new question for that, would be great, if you can help me out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44324189/rails-category-as-self-referenced-model