# rails category as self referenced model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a category model, which' use case is to be a topcategory, category or subcategory.

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subcategories, class_name: "Category", foreign_key: "parent_id"
  belongs_to :topcategory, class_name: "Category"

  has_many :skills
end

class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
end
```

1) How can I list for each Category (hierarchly structured) the linked skills with a `collection_check_boxes` as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44282875/8090895

2) I need to list those categories in a hierarchical list like this example

```
topcategory1
-Skill1, Skill2, Skill6
-category1
--Skill3, Skill4
--Subcategory1
---Skill7, Skill8
--Subcategory2
---Skill5
-category2
topcategory2
...
```

How could I do that?

My current controller setup for categories is:

```
@all_categories = Category.includes(:subcategories, :skills)
@topcategories = @all_categories.where("parent_id IS NULL")
@categories = @all_categories.where("parent_id IS NOT NULL")
```

3) For creating new skills, I need a Dropdown with a structured list of all categories. I found only the possibility to use `options_from_collection_for_select` but here I can't select the "maingroups" themselves. And in my Use Case I even need all tree instances to be selectable.

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance for tips and help. If you need any more information, just go for it.

Edit1 for part 3): Another idea was to fill the Dropdown List like this:

```
Topcategory1//
Topcategory1//Category1//
Topcategory1//Category1//Subcategory1
Topcategory1//Category1//Subcategory2
Topcategory2//
Topcategory2//Category2//
Topcategory2//Category2//Subcategory3
...
```

This would/should be a normal list, which makes it possible to select any category element. The fact, that the Top- and Categories are displayed multiple times is ok for me. I just don't have any idea, how I could fill up the dropdown like this.

Comment: You should just use gem like awesome_nested_set

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice. I attempt to use only few gems but I guess that one is necessary. Any suggestion for 1) and 3)?

Comment: yes, it's much performant to query nested records by lft and rght values. just index

Answer (score 0):

Start by creating a self-joining association for categories:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Category',
                      optional: true
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Category', 
                      foreign_key: 'category_id'
end
```

This allows you to nest categories infinitely if needed and keeps the records in a single table. Which is vital if you need to reorganize the categorization.

You can then setup the association between skills and categories:

```
class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
end
```

To join the categories and skills for the subcategories you can do:

```
@categories = Category.left_joins(:skills, children: [:skills])
@top_level = @categories.select { |c| c.parent.nil? }
```

> 3) For creating new skills, I need a Dropdown with a structured list
>   of all categories. I found only the possibility to use
>   `options_from_collection_for_select` but here I can't select the
>   "maingroups" themselves. And in my Use Case I even need all tree
>   instances to be selectable.

Unfortunatly the HTML spec does not allow nested `<optgroup>` elements. You can fake nesting by indenting the options. There are also several javascript options such as Select2 which can make it more usable.

```html
<select name="person[skill_ids]" multiple="true">
  <optgroup label="Programming">
    <option value="1">GIT</option>
  </optgroup> 
  <optgroup label="&nbsp;&nbsp;Programming Languages" class="level-2">
    <option value="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Ruby</option>
    <option value="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Python</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Using the rails grouped collection helpers might not work so well for you use case. So you might need to manually create the options:

```
<select name="person[skill_ids]">
  <%= @top_level.each do |tc| %>
    <optgroup label="<%= tc.name %>" class="parent-category">
      <%= options_for_select(tc.skills.map { |s| [s.name, s.id] })
    </optgroup>
    <%= tc.children.each do |subcategory| %>
      <optgroup label="&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= subcategory.name %>" class="subcategory">
        <%= options_for_select(subcategory.skills.map { |s| ["&nbsp;&nbsp;#{s.name}", s.id] }) %>
      </optgroup>
    <% end %>
  </optgroup>
  <% end %>
</select>
```

Here you would also check if the form object has the skill and apply the selected attribute to the `<option>`.

Comment: I hope this points you in the right direction - I'm really strapped for time today so I apologise for any errors. The whole last bit could be done much better if you programatically create the html in a helper method instead of using ERB.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I will try to adapt your suggestions. I have already though about an idea like in "Edit1 for part 3)" but I have no idea, how to fill the list.